# AngularJS controller as and this instead of $scope calling $apply in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been using the controller as syntax and this instead of `$scope` in my Angular project and ran across an issue using a directive.  I'm trying to call a function in my controller using `scope.$apply()` in the directive.  But since I'm not using scope in the controller, I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I understand why because of the scope issue, but my question is what's the correct way to use `$apply` in my directive using controller as and this instead of `$scope`?

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z6476omb/

```
angular
    .module('testApp',[])
    .controller('TestCtrl',TestCtrl)
    .directive('updateDirective',updateDirective)


function TestCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = 'Rob'
    vm.updateName = updateName;

    function updateName(new_name) {
        vm.name = 'Robert';
    }
}

function updateDirective() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict:'A'
    }

    return directive;

    function link(scope,element,attr) {
        element.on('click',function() {
            console.log('trying to change...');
            scope.$apply(scope.updateName());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to refer to the controller scope using the alias you used:  `ctrl`.

So in your directive, you can do refer to it as:  `scope.ctrl.updateName()`

See fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6476omb/1/

Comment: It worked!  It would have taken a while to figure that out.  I appreciate your help.